# Non-blank ng-app name stops expression being evaluated

Tags: angularjs

Why does `ng-app="myApp"` cause the expression to not evaluate?

If I use `ng-app=""`, it works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="quantity=2;price=5">

<h2>Cost Calculator</h2>

Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity">
Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price">

<p><b>Total in dollar:</b> {{quantity * price}}</p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See [Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr). This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception.

Comment: Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: I have no js code. So basically if you have a non-blank ngApp name, then you have to have angular.module("appNameHere", []); in the javascript code?

Comment: Value provided to `ng-app` is name of main module...yes